# Why is my tif file a BigTIFF file but the size is less than 4 Gb?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, bigtiff

I have a TIFF file of first day beyond 10 degrees at 2 m height covering the northern part of North America. The size of the file is 1.24 Gb, but when I load it into Python (3.7) I get the classic `This is a BigTIFF` error.
I do not understand why I get that error. Here is the TIFF file information:

```
CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
Extent  -172.5304334680000125,35.3037906650000011 : -52.5694104270000224,83.1300963930000023
Unit    degrees
Width   26708
Height  10648
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dimensions  X: 26708 Y: 10648 Bands: 21
Origin  -172.53,83.1301
Pixel Size  0.004491576420585592123,-0.004491576420736288419
```

I thought the limit was 4 Gb; so why do I get this error?
Here is the beginning of the script until the error:

```
import gdal  # raster management
import ogr  # vector managment
import numpy as np  # gridded data
import os  # file managment
import csv  # for saving results in csv format
path = "D:/temperature/"
#%%
#load data
r_ds = gdal.Open(path + '2mheight/temperature2m_NA.tif')
```

Answer (score 3):

TIFF cannot be larger than 4 GB but there is no other lower limit for the size of BigTIFF than the size of the compulsory headers. It is for example possible to create a single pixel BigTIFF file that has a filesize of only 253 bytes with gdal_create command

`gdal_create -outsize 1 1 -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=yes small_bigtiff.tif`

That the file is a BigTIFF can be verified with a hex editor. The file begins with bytes

`49 49 2B 00 08 00 00 00`

http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/BigTIFF#Identification

Your image is rather big and the program that has written it may have considered that the size may reach the 4 GB limit so it is safer to create the image as BigTIFF.

This is how the the GDAL GeoTIFF driver makes a decision between TIFF and BigTIFF https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

> BIGTIFF=YES/NO/IF_NEEDED/IF_SAFER: Control whether the created file is
> a BigTIFF or a classic TIFF.
>
> YES forces BigTIFF.
>
> NO forces classic TIFF.
>
> IF_NEEDED will only create a BigTIFF if it is clearly needed (in the
> uncompressed case, and image larger than 4GB. So no effect when using
> a compression).
>
> IF_SAFER will create BigTIFF if the resulting file *might* exceed 4GB.
> Note: this is only a heuristics that might not always work depending
> on compression ratios.
>
> BigTIFF is a TIFF variant which can contain more than 4GiB of data
> (size of classic TIFF is limited by that value). This option is
> available if GDAL is built with libtiff library version 4.0 or higher.
> The default is IF_NEEDED.
>
> When creating a new GeoTIFF with no compression, GDAL computes in
> advance the size of the resulting file. If that computed file size is
> over 4GiB, GDAL will automatically decide to create a BigTIFF file.
> However, when compression is used, it is not possible in advance to
> known the final size of the file, so classical TIFF will be chosen. In
> that case, the user must explicitly require the creation of a BigTIFF
> with BIGTIFF=YES if the final file is anticipated to be too big for
> classical TIFF format. If BigTIFF creation is not explicitly asked or
> guessed and the resulting file is too big for classical TIFF, libtiff
> will fail with an error message like “TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF
> file size exceeded”.

You can convert your file into TIFF with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co BIGTIFF=NO input.tif output.tif
```